# HTML Table Rows - How to make a unique cell have 100% width? (with screenshot explanation)

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's my problem: I have an HTML table that looks like this:

[image: HTML Table]

What I want is for there to be an additional table row underneath it, except this row spans the full width of the table - but with *just one cell*. I quickly mocked up an example:

[image: table]

As you can see I added another Table Row below it with a single `<td>` cell inside containing the text. However I want this cell to span 100% of the width of the entire table - it shouldn't resize the width of the 'Name' column.

Is such a thing possible? I am happy to use jQuery or Javascript if needs be - also, this doesn't need to work in IE as every user is using Chrome (although that would be a perk).

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In your case, you'd do something like

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">This text should be as long as the entire table's width...</td>
</tr>
```

The `colspan` attribute says how many columns the cell should take up.  It should work in all browsers that support tables, as it's standard HTML.

In JavaScript, you'd set the `colSpan` property of the cell, or call `.setAttribute("colspan", the_number_of_columns)` on it.  Either should work.  But unless you're generating the cell dynamically, you should just include the `colspan` attribute in your HTML.

Comment: Perfect - thank you! I haven't gone anywhere near tables after hearing about their general hatred from developers - until now, when I actually needed to display tabular data :-)

Comment: Tables on their own are not evil.  They're actually pretty good for what they're made for.  If you ever hear someone tell you all tables are bad, you can be pretty confident that he/she is a cargo cultist and doesn't know WTF they're actually saying.  :)  It's *layout tables* -- using tables to position stuff, rather than to hold tabular data -- that are evil.  (Still very rarely necessary, but evil even then.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saved my time and helped to get a thing solved. all best for oyu

Answer (score 27):

For one cell to span all 5 columns,

```
<td colspan="5">Lorem Ipsum</td>
```